# Extract day of week from date field in PostgreSQL assuming weeks start on Monday

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

```
select extract(dow from datefield)
```

extract a number from 0 to 6, where 0 is Sunday; is there a way to get the day of the week in SQL assuming that weeks start on Monday (so 0 will be Monday)?

Comment: `date_part('isodow', datefield)-1`

Answer (score 111, accepted):

[From the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

```
isodow

    The day of the week as Monday (1) to Sunday (7)
```

So, you just need to subtract 1 from that result:

```
psql (9.6.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> select extract(isodow from date '2016-12-12') - 1;
  ?column?
-----------
         0
(1 row)
postgres=>
```

Comment: Deriving from the current datetime: `SELECT EXTRACT(isodow from date (NOW()::date))`

Comment: @Nae: `now()::date`  can be simplified to `current_date`

Answer (score 55):

Use date_part Function **dow()**

Here  0=Sunday, 1=Monday, 2=Tuesday, ... 6=Saturday

```
   select extract(dow from date '2016-12-18'); /* sunday */
```

> Output : 0

```
    select extract(isodow from date '2016-12-12'); /* Monday  */
```

> Ouput :  1

Answer (score 45):

If you want the text version of the weekday then you can use the `to_char(date, format)` function supplying a date and the format that you want.

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE we have the following format options we can use for date. I have shown some examples for output. According to the documentation the abbreviated day values are 3 characters long in English, other locales may vary.

```
select To_Char("Date", 'DAY'), * from "MyTable"; -- TUESDAY
select To_Char("Date", 'Day'), * from "MyTable"; -- Tuesday
select To_Char("Date", 'day'), * from "MyTable"; -- tuesday
select To_Char("Date", 'dy'), * from "MyTable";  -- tue
select To_Char("Date", 'Dy'), * from "MyTable";  -- Tue
select To_Char("Date", 'DY'), * from "MyTable";  -- TUE
select To_Char("Date", 'D'), * from "MyTable";   -- 3 From Docs:    day of the week, Sunday (1) to Saturday (7)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with a as (select extract(isodow from date '2020-02-28') - 1 a ),
b as(select CASE 
         WHEN a.a=0 THEN 'Sunday'
         WHEN a.a =1 THEN 'Monday'
         WHEN a.a =2 THEN 'Tuesday'
         WHEN a.a=3 THEN 'Wednesday'
         WHEN a.a=4 THEN 'Thursday'
         WHEN a.a=5 THEN 'Friday'
         WHEN a.a=6 THEN 'Saturday'
     ELSE 'other'
   END from a ) 
 select * from b;
```

Comment: The logic here is fine (and helpful), but the text assignment is incorrect.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-datetime.html:
_The day of the week as Sunday (0) to Saturday (6) . . .
  
Note that **extract's day of the week numbering differs from that of the to_char(..., 'D')** function._

So, Bharti's comment will work well though for to_char(), but for extract(), make sure your Sunday is 0

Comment: Updated the example (as mentioned by Dan) to save people from copy pasting the incorrect code.