# Get the number of the weekday from each date in a date list

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=edcf0bc39497b87aada3b144403859c2)**

```
CREATE TABLE dates (
    date_list DATE
);

INSERT INTO dates
(date_list)
VALUES 
('2020-01-29'),
('2020-01-30'),
('2020-01-31'),
('2020-02-01'),
('2020-02-02');
```

**Expected Results:**

```
  Weekday
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
```

---

I want go get the number of the weekday for each date in the table dates. 
Therefore, I tried to go with the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181990/extract-day-of-week-from-date-field-in-postgresql-assuming-weeks-start-on-monday) but could not make it work:

```
SELECT 
EXTRACT(DOW FROM DATE d.date_list))
FROM dates d
```

How do I need to modify the query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `date` keyword it is only needed to introduce a DATE *constant*. If you already have a DATE *value* (which your column is) it's not needed:

```
select extract(dow from d.date_list)
from dates d
```